# PIR sensor issues

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

**The code works but there was a problem on the output. When the PIR detect the presence of motion the output (pin 12) would not give an instant HIGH state on the output, it has more than 10 sec delay to provide a HIGH state on PIN 12. HOw can I lessen the time that once the PIR sensors detected motion it would give a HIGH state to the output (pin 12)? please help me regarding this problem! Thanks**

```
 void setup()
{
    //Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    pinMode(13,OUTPUT);//output 1
    pinMode(12,OUTPUT);//output 2
    int pirOuts=11;pinMode(pirOuts,INPUT); /*PIR sensor 1*/
    int pirOut = 10;pinMode(pirOut,INPUT); /*PIR sensor 2*/


    if (digitalRead(pirOut) || digitalRead(pirOuts) == HIGH){ 
        digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
        tone(13, 50132); delay(100); noTone(13); delay(10);
        tone(13,54621);  delay(50);  noTone(13); delay(50);
        tone(13,35689);  delay(60);  noTone(13);
    } 
    else if (digitalRead(pirOut)||digitalRead(pirOuts)==LOW){
        digitalWrite(12,LOW);
        tone(13,50132); delay(100); noTone(13); delay(10);
        tone(13,54621);  delay(50);  noTone(13); delay(50);
        tone(13,35689);  delay(60);  noTone(13);
    } 
    else
    {}
}
```

Comment: "digitalRead(pirOut) || digitalRead(pirOuts) == HIGH" is actually "digitalRead(pirOut) == HIGH || digitalRead(pirOuts) == HIGH" and "digitalRead(pirOut) || digitalRead(pirOuts)==LOW" is actually "digitalRead(pirOut)==HIGH || digitalRead(pirOuts)==LOW". Also pinMode(), if fixed, are often done once in the setup().

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure your PIR sensor reads high when triggered. Most of them will trigger high, but I've seen a few that will trigger low. Also, some PIR sensors have potentiometers to control delay. Some delay the trigger, some delay the reset between triggers.

The delay may not be coming from the Arduino, but from the sensor itself.

Note, the first if statement is formatted incorrectly:

```
if (digitalRead(pirOut) || digitalRead(pirOuts) == HIGH)
```

should probably be:

```
if (digitalRead(pirOut) == HIGH || digitalRead(pirOuts) == HIGH)
```

It works the way you coded it because you're doing a logical OR of the two input values (which will be 0 or 1) then comparing the result to HIGH. As I said it will work, but probably not best practice.

Also, in your code, I don't understand why you're using else if instead of just else.

```
else if (digitalRead(pirOut)||digitalRead(pirOuts)==LOW){
```

Basically, your first if statement has to be false (so both pirOut and pirOuts must both be low) so your if statement as written will always be true.

If your intent was to execute that code when either pirOut or pirOuts goes LOW, then it should be a separate if statement, not an else if.